# MYSQL select only users who made more than 1 record, without grouping

Tags: mysql

I have **UserLogs** table and query for logs monitoring

```
SELECT from_unixtime(logDate/1000) as logDate, userId, userAction FROM UserLogs
WHERE logDate > subdate(now(), INTERVAL 1 day )
```

I want to improve it with showing in result only users who have more than 1 record, without grouping.

### Example:

**User A** made 1 record for a day, **user B** made 5 records and **user C** made 3 records for same day. SQL result will show 8 columns -  5 records from **user B** and 3 records from **user C**.

---

```html
<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <td>UserId</td>
  <td>Time</td>
  <td>Action</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>11.56</td>
  <td>POST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>11.57</td>
  <td>DELETE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>11.58</td>
  <td>COMMENT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>11.59</td>
  <td>DELETE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td>11.60</td>
  <td>EDIT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>11.60</td>
  <td>EDIT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>11.60</td>
  <td>COMMENT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td>11.60</td>
  <td>POST</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Why without grouping?  using a group by and a count seem to be efficient.  way to do this. and achieve your 8 records ( I hope not columns)

Comment: In result I need additional info, action for example ant it can be different

Comment: Add some sample data and expected results  using the approach I've listed in an answer you could join to additional tables to get additional data and still keep the grouping...

Comment: I have added simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT from_unixtime(logDate/1000) as logDate, userId 
FROM UserLogs UL1
INNER JOIN (SELECT userID, from_UnixTime(logDate/1000) logDate, count(1) cnt 
            FROM userLogs 
            GROUP BY  userID, from_UnixTime(logDate/1000)
            HAVING count(1)>1) UL2
  on UL1.userID = UL2.UserID 
 and UL1.LogDate = from_unixtime(UL1.logDate/1000)
WHERE logDate > subdate(now(), INTERVAL 1 day )
```

What this does is generate a subset of the users days for users having more than 1 entry. it then joins back to the base set to return all 8 records for users on those days; excluding the users having only a count of 1.

Instead of a join you could use an exists statement which may be slightly faster.